# Auto-populate Detailsview insert textbox with value from dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, detailsview

I am trying to auto populate the textbox for the field clientId while the detailsview is in insert mode.

It needs to end up like this...
    http://s7.postimg.org/o7d48cfvv/Untitled.png

```
name *textbox*
address *textbox*
phone *textbox*
email *textbox*
clientId *AUTOPOPULATED* - based on dropdownlist1.value
```

I looked around and couldnt find a solution anywhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to achieve this you need to make the last field(clientId) on your detailsview control as a template field and then set the value of InsertItemTemplate to the value of drop down list, here is an example for you:

your .aspx web form:
//e.g. this is your dropdown list

> ```
>  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
>                     <asp:ListItem>id1</asp:ListItem>
>                     <asp:ListItem>id2</asp:ListItem>
>                     <asp:ListItem>id3</asp:ListItem>
>                 </asp:DropDownList>
> ```

//e.g. your detailsview control

> ```
>  <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateRows="False">
>                     <Fields>
>                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Firstname" HeaderText="Firstname" SortExpression="Firstname" />
>                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
>                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Suburb" HeaderText="Suburb" SortExpression="Suburb" />
>                         <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State" SortExpression="State" />
>                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Postcode" HeaderText="Postcode" SortExpression="Postcode" />
>                         <asp:BoundField DataField="MPhone" HeaderText="MPhone" SortExpression="MPhone" />
>                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Username" SortExpression="Username">
>                             <EditItemTemplate>
>                                 <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Username") %>' ID="Label1"></asp:Label>
>                             </EditItemTemplate>
>                             <InsertItemTemplate>
>                                 <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value %>' ID="TextBox1"></asp:TextBox>
>                             </InsertItemTemplate>
>                             <ItemTemplate>
>                                 <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>' ID="Label1"></asp:Label>
>                             </ItemTemplate>
>                         </asp:TemplateField>
>
>                         <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True"></asp:CommandField>
>                     </Fields>
>                 </asp:DetailsView>
> ```

so when you select a value from the dropdownlist above and click on new command on your detailsviewcontrol it will pickup the value from the list and bind it to the textbox as a value, like the snapshot below:

[image]